# Completeness of $L^\infty$

Tags: banach-spaces

I found a simple proof for the completeness of $L^\infty$, based on the fact that a normed vector space is complete if 
$$\sum_n ||f_n||<\infty \implies \exists y=\sum_n f_n$$
I am not sure that the last passages work.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^\infty(\Omega,\mu)$ such that 
$$\sum_n ||f_n||_\infty=M<\infty$$
then by definition of ess sup exists $\{\Omega_n\}_n$ such that
$\mu(\Omega_n^c)=0$ for all $n$ and 
$$\sup_{\Omega_n} f_n=||f_n||_\infty$$
then,

> since $\mu((\cap_n \Omega_n)^c)=\mu(\cup_n \Omega_n^c)=0$, we have 
>   $$||\sum_n f_n||_\infty\le \sum_n ||f_n||_\infty<M$$
>   So $\sum_n f_n\in L^\infty$

Does the formulas in the rectangle hold?

Comment: "... if every sum converges absolutely." What does this mean? Do you mean that every absolutely convergent series converges?

Comment: An other characterization of Banach space is that $\sum_n ||x_n||<\infty\implies \exists y =\sum_n x_n$

Comment: Yes, but this is not what you have written in your question.

Comment: Edited. Have you got any suggestion?